# Populating choicebox with enum

Tags: java, enums, javafx

I've begun to design an simple GUI application that allow me to add  NBA player information to a database. I have ran into an issue that I cannot seem to find a solution to online.

My issue is that I cannot seem to populate my ChoiceBox Ive created in SceneBuilder with the values in a enum I've created.

```
public class Controller implements Initializable {
@FXML
private ChoiceBox <newTeam> teamId;
@Override
public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1) {
    assert teamId != null;
    teamId.getItems().setAll(newTeam.values());
}
```

And this is the enum class

```
public class Team {

public enum newTeam {
    Hawks("Atlanta Hawks"), Celtics("Boston Celtics"), Hornets(
            "Charlotte Hornets"), Bulls("Chicago Bulls");

    private String name;

    newTeam(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }

}
```

}

Comment: What actually happens when you try this?

Comment: *"Cannot seem to"*, what's that mean? What's the actual problem?

Comment: Ah, now it seems to work. I had other instance variables above the Choicebox one initially and I was getting a Null Pointer Exception error.  I removed them for the sake of brevity. So am I right in saying that you have to put the @FXML annotation above every instance you create using SceneBuilder?

Comment: You have to annotate every field you want the `FXMLLoader` to inject into the controller with `@FXML`, yes. See, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29847703/nullpointer-exception-during-initialize-fxml-injection-not-working-as-expected/29848310#29848310